# Using sed to remove unwanted characters from output

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I am running the following command in a bash shell in an attempt to return only the hexadecimal characters inside the `[]` and the integer value immediately following.  The first sed call replaces everything up to and including the `[`.  The second replaces `:` and `]`. The command produces the desired result however I'd like to accomplish this in a single sed statement, i.e. without having to pipe through sed a second time.  I've attempted a good many combinations of these two regex expressions but have not been able to find a combination that produces the desired result.

```
echo 'dot1dTpFdbPort[00:02:6f:d9:16:ca] 12' | sed 's/^.*\[//g' | sed 's/[][\:]//g'
00026fd916ca 12
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe you can try using the two regex with one unique sed command:

```
echo 'dot1dTpFdbPort[00:02:6f:d9:16:ca] 12' | sed -e 's/^.*\[//g' -e 's/[][\:]//g'
```

That command produces your desired result exactly what you want: in only one sed stetment.

Saludos.

Comment: Can be shorten to: `sed -e 's/^.*\[//g;s/[][\:]//g'`

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 'dot1dTpFdbPort[00:02:6f:d9:16:ca] 12' | sed 's/^.*\[//;s/[][\:]//g'
```

Comment: g in first `s` action is not needed

Answer (score 0):

Some like this?

```
echo 'dot1dTpFdbPort[00:02:6f:d9:16:ca] 12' | awk '{gsub(/[^[]*\[|]|:/,"")}8'
00026fd916ca 12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'dot1dTpFdbPort[00:02:6f:d9:16:ca] 12' | sed 's/://g;s/.*\[\(.*\)\]/\1/'
```

similar but based on content extraction