# Unable to parse bash output using regex and collect a part of it

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I am trying to parse out the recent load, from the output of this command -

```
[sandeepan@ip-10-169-92-150 ~]$ w
 14:22:21 up 17 days, 51 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
sandeepa pts/0    115.112.95.170   06:38   43:57   0.51s  0.51s -bash
sandeepa pts/1    115.112.95.170   13:17    4.00s  0.03s  0.00s w
```

The first one after the load average: -

```
                |
               \|/
load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
```

I was using this, which worked -

```
w | awk '{print $10}' | tr -d ,
```

However, I realised that the value I am looking for may not always be the 10th variable. Hence I am trying to use regex here, but unfortunately, not able to use it with any of the few bash commands/utilities I know.

I have this regular expression, with which I am able to match the desired value -

```
/.*load average:\s([0-9]+\.[0-9]+),.*/m
```

I tried looking at the sed manual, looking at some other questions like [Using sed to remove unwanted characters from output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22078519/using-sed-to-remove-unwanted-characters-from-output), but could not understand much to make mine working.

Comment: Maybe take a look at `/proc/loadavg`, rather than trying to parse a human-readable format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you know what text comes before and after, it is best to use a look-behind that does this: checks the text in a given place, no matter what is the rest of the line.

Given your sample file, I stored it in a file and did this:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=load average: )[^,]*' file
0.00
```

This is saying: hey, get all the text after `load average:` and until a comma is found.

So if you have a file like this:

```
$ cat file
14:22:21 up 17 days, 51 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
hello how are you,  load average: 1.23, 0.01, 0.05
```

It will return as follows:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=load average: )[^,]*' file
0.00
1.23
```

---

Note by the way that `man w` can give you good hints on how to get this info with some options, as well as `man top`.